# How to show vertical scroll indicator in Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I use vimperator and know how to remove the the scrollbar (set guioptions-=rl) but I would like to have a scroll percentage in the status bar similar to how vim does. Is there anyway to do this in Vimperator? I didn't see anything in the vimperator options for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Munra for reminding me about this post. I've since learned that I has just forgotten to enable the statusbar on the Firefox side.

So I had to do something like view->toolbars->show status bar and then the status bar with it's scrolling percentage showed up.